# Network requests not captured by Firebase Performance

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-performance

I develop an iOS application (Swift 4) and I have successfully added Firebase Performance to make custom traces.

But I also want to monitor network performance and unfortunately, the network requests initiated from my application are not captured (but network requests made by crashlytics are captured correctly).

As mentioned in the official documentation, there are known issues about Firebase Performance on iOS:

- Performance Monitoring does not support network requests made using the NSURLConnection class
- If your app uses delegate methods of the NSURLSession class and does not implement all of the possible delegate methods, those sessions might not be correctly captured by HTTP/S network request monitoring

I use NSURLSession and not NSURLConnection so the first issue is not applicable.

I use a custom delegate but I have implemented all the possible delegate methods (to conform the 2nd issue).

Any ideas why it doesn't work and how to solve the problem ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Do you still have this problem? The automated network collection in Firebase Performance requires a minimum number of events before they will appear in the console. Usually in a released app, this isn't an issue. But if you've just added the SDK or a new URL endpoint and are manually testing, it will take a few iterations to get enough samples to display.

The same applies for more complex URL patterns: The URL paths will be broken down to finer levels of detail as more events are collected.

Comment: Yes the issue is still there and I think that the number of requests is not a problem.

10 people uses the application since 3 weeks and hundreds of requests are made every day.

Comment: Can you file a ticket through https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/ and also include bundle id. We can then look into more detail as to what's going wrong.

Comment: Got it. We're taking a look. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I have the same issue on Android. Will file a bug.

Comment: This was the result of a bug in processing NSMutableURLRequests that was fixed in the 4.7.0 release of Firebase iOS.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. I'm using Firebase Performance SDK `6.13.0`